# Teradata SQL - Very Large Pulls

Tags: sql, teradata

So I have a query that's returning more rows than MS Excel can handle (2 million), does anyone have any advice on getting Teradata to export to multiple Excel tabs, or maybe a way to break big query results up so that I can run the query to only pull more manageable chunks each time?

I know there are commands like **TOP** and **SAMPLE** which will only return a given portion of a pull, but I'm unclear on what the logic would be to rank a query and then return, say the *TOP 100000*, and then to run the same/similar query a second time but this time to have it return records *100001 - 200000*, and then the time after that it returns *200001 - 300000*, and so on.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!  I know I can export to a text CSV but it would definitely be easier if I can figure out a way for Teradata to play nice with Excel. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to assign an "ID" value to each row in your result set and then get the results in whatever chunks you want.  Something like:

```
SELECT col1, col2, ...
FROM MyTable
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
    ORDER BY Unique_Col
) BETWEEN <Start_Number> AND <End_Number>
```

Just make sure to use a Unique column or columns in the `ORDER BY` so that tbe `ROW_NUMBER` function applies the same ordering each time you run the query.

This doesn't take into account if there are changes to rows in your result set (i.e. added/deleted rows) in between query runs.  If that's a concern, copy the rows first to a temp table and then run your queries against the temp table.

Comment: Thank you so much, that is exactly what I was looking for!  Appreciate it very much.   :)

Comment: No prob bob :) .